# Reload tableview rows not working unless I scroll

Tags: swift, tableview, reloaddata

I am currently using a folding cell library and when i close the cell, the labels(dates) and images(workout type) should reload.

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
  tableView.reloadRows(at: indexSet, with: .none)
}
tableView.endUpdates()
```

I have tried putting my reloadRows in a dispatchQueue.main.async call and everything else that is similar to mine question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `self.tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: tableView.reloadData is fine but I have a header with a chart and I am using a tableviewcontroller so I don't want to keep redrawing my chart. So I am just trying to reload my rows but when I do I have to scroll for the UI to update.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem normally occurs when you have not reloaded your tableViews , i.e your Data Source method cellForRowAtIndexPath is not populate tableview elements . 
so , try with reload tableView like below

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: tableView.reloadData is fine but I have a header with a chart and I am using a tableviewcontroller so I don't want to keep redrawing my chart